# Determine edition of Windows 7 Bootcamp partition - no access to command line(?)

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, bootloader, boot-camp

I acquired a MacBook recently with a Windows 7 Bootcamp partition. I wanted to make more space for the Windows partition, so used MacOS' Disk Utility to shrink the MacOS partition.

Even though this [was apparently not a detrimental move in previous versions of MacOS](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/reszie-boot-camp-partition.html) (see the "Alternatively:" section of the link), resizing the Mac partition in current versions of MacOS makes the Windows partition unbootable. The Windows partition now no longer shows up at all on the boot menu (the menu that displays on boot while holding the Option key).

I found multiple instances online where people fixed their Bootcamp partition by booting into a Windows 7 Install/Recovery USB and choosing the "Repair your computer" option ([Example](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7665330?answerId=30646981022#30646981022)).

I did not know which version of Windows 7 was installed on this machine, so I acquired a Windows 7 x64 SP1 Professional ISO and used Bootcamp to install the ISO onto my 4GB flash drive. I was successfully able to boot into the Windows 7 USB, but when I selected "Repair your computer," I got the following error:

> "This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the
>   version of windows you are trying to repair. Try using a recovery disc
>   that is compatible with this version of windows."

I therefore assume that the problem is that the Windows Partition is using a Windows 7 x64 OS of an edition other than Professional. Is there a way for me to know what version of Windows is installed from the MacOS side so I can acquire the correct boot/recovery disc?

Answer (score 1):

This stack is littered with people who've tried MiniTool & failed miserably.
Avoid like the plague.

The golden rule is never touch the partitioning from within Windows. It simply doesn't understand how it's being fooled into thinking it's in charge.

Your only hope now is probably [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) which has a free trial. It may be able to fix what you've already broken & then is one of only 3 tools that can effectively move APFS & the wrapped MBR without breaking it.

Paragon -
[Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/)
[CampTune](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/)
TwoCanoes -
[WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/)

*[I have no affiliation with either company.]*

It is possible to fix this from Terminal, but requires some seriously arcane methodology. I'd buy the tool.

Comment: You have valuable insight. I wish I could have foreseen this useful answer because instead of waiting for your response I let my impatience take over and just deleted all my partitions (except MacOS) and reinstalled Bootcamp. (I only remembered afterword that I had a big library of files on my Windows partition I wanted to keep.) So, for future reference, what is the safest method to expand the Windows partition on a GPT/MBR hybrid Bootcamp system?

Comment: Paragon’s HDM is the one I use the most. It can move, resize, create & also backup & restore all partition types. CampTune is just for resizing. WinClone is comprehensive but I haven’t really put it through its paces.